# annotation attribute KafkaListener.topics must be an array initializer or Constant Expression

Tags: annotations, apache-kafka

I am currently using Spring Kafka API's

We currently have a requirement to dynamically add a suffix to Kafka topics. While trying to modify and set it back to Annotation "@KafkaListener" as follows -

@KafkaListener(topics = modifiedTopics )

It gives me an error saying - The value for annotation attribute KafkaListener.topics must be an array initializer

or if I try the code one below - (with flower braces)

@KafkaListener(topics = {modifiedTopics} )

It gives me error saying - The value for annotation attribute KafkaListener.topics must be a constant expression

Has anyone faced similar issues with annotataions? If yes, kindly help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is: One of the way to add lambda into annotation is as follows:
 In the KafkaReceiver class's method -

```
 @Autowired
      TopicUtil                      topicUtil;


      @KafkaListener(topics = "#{topicUtil.suffixTopics()}")


      //In the TopicUtil - add the follwoing method

      public String[] suffixTopics() {
          return Arrays.asList(pTopics.split(",")).stream().map(p -> p + envSuffix).toArray(String[]::new);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

**application.yaml**:

```
spring:
  topic:
    name: ${EVENT_HUB_NAME}
```

**Kafka Consumer**:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.topic.name}", containerFactory = "myKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(String event) {
      log.info("consumed: {}", event);
      // do something
    }
```

Comment: not sure why it was voted down